# how to do internal redirect with spray routing

Tags: scala, redirect, routes, spray

I want to do something similar with spray routing

If server receive request

- `http://myserver/a/1`  then respond it with content
- `http://myserver/a/2`  then temp redirect to `http://myserver/b` ;
  however since this is internal redirect prefer not to send
  redirect to client and let client make another http get call to new
  url; rather would prefer do an internal redirect
- `http://myserver/b` then respond with content

Below is the program I have come up with ; i would like to get comments from others on this and if i can make it better by removing 2 references of **routeB** in the code

```
class RedirectTestService(val actorRefFactory: ActorRefFactory) extends HttpService {

  //For troubleshooting purpose only 
  val extractURI = extract { ctx =>
    ctx.request.uri
  }

  def mapRequestContextWithPath(pathStr: String) = mapRequestContext(_.copy(unmatchedPath = Path(pathStr)))

  val routeB = extractURI { uri =>
    println("For troubleshooting" + uri)
    pathPrefix("b") {
      get {
        complete {
          "got a B"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  val routeA = pathPrefix("a" / IntNumber) { id =>
    get {
      if (id == 1)
        complete {
          "got an A with id = " + id
        }
      else {
        mapRequestContextWithPath("/b") {
          routeB
        }
      }
    }
  }
  val route = routeA ~ routeB
}

// this trait defines our service behavior independently from the service actor
trait TestService extends HttpService {
  val myRoute = // new LongerService(actorRefFactory).route
    new RedirectTestService(actorRefFactory).route
}

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class RedirectTestServiceTest extends Specification with Specs2RouteTest with TestService {
  def actorRefFactory = system

  "RedirectTestService" should {
    "return response" in {
      Get("/a/1") ~> myRoute ~> check {
        responseAs[String] === "got an A with id = 1"
      }

      Get("/b") ~> myRoute ~> check {
        responseAs[String] === "got a B"
      }

      Get("/a/2") ~> myRoute ~> check {
        responseAs[String] === "got a B"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is fine to accomplish what you need. I don't see a downside to mentioning `routeB` twice.